# SemiFixed: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a rails app (Rails 4.1.0) from scratch and I am getting a problem that I am not able to solve. I have installed and configured Apache Passenger Module, it works fine. Any time I try to access the virtual host I get an error 500:

```
Missing secret_key_base for 'production' environment, set this value in config/secrets.yml
```

The secret.yml file contains the following configuration:

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Even when it's not recommended I did this:

```
    production:
  secret_key_base: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX (random key)
```

But Apache logs show this:

```
# tailf /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
[Tue May 06 12:56:18 2014] [error] [client 192.168.3.1] Premature end of script headers:
App 4405 stderr: [ 2014-05-06 12:56:18.5763 4421/0x9d48bdc(Worker 1) utils.rb:68 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object (Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`) (process 4421, thread 0x9d48bdc(Worker 1)):
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:440:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in `env_config'
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
App 4405 stderr:        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

How I can fix this error? How do I access the development enviroment? I mean how I can write code, test in my browser and then deploy to Heroku or just test in production enviroment?

**Update**

I manage to fix the error above by setting `RailsEnv development` on VirtualHost but now I get this other error:

> SQLite3::CantOpenException unable to open database file
>   Rails.root: /var/www/html/moviedb

I'm trying to use [this GEM](https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb/) for make queries to TheMovieDB website and get results. Any advice on this new error?

Comment: The excerpt you posted from your YAML is not indented correctly. Is it an error in the paste? YAML is very sensitive to indentation - `secret_key_base:` should be out-dented by two spaces from `production:`.

Comment: Just so you know using ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] is looking for the system environment variable called SECRET_KEY_BASE. If you can ssh onto the host then 
`SECRET_KEY_BASE=\`rake secret\` `
 in the rails directory should set it. To check it has worked you can 
`echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE`
Note: this probably isn't the issue if you have directly set in in the config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did : On my production server, I create a config file (confthin.yml) for Thin (I'm using it) and add the following information :

environment: production
user: www-data
group: www-data
SECRET_KEY_BASE: mysecretkeyproduction

I then launch the app with

thin start -C /whereeveristhefieonprod/configthin.yml

Work like a charm and then no need to have the secret key on version control

Hope it could help, but I'm sure the same thing could be done with Unicorn and others.

Comment: I get the error `gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:147:in \`parse!': invalid option: --SECRET-KEY-BASE=<key> (OptionParser::InvalidOption)`

Answer (score 20):

**Rails app secret key via bash**

If you have access to the `bash`console of *the user* that is running the rails app, and if you are not using `thin`, then you could provide the environment variable via the users `~/.bashrc`

*just add the following:*

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=`MY_SECRET_KEY`
```

Note: MY_SECRET_KEY could be anything but it would be secure to generate a key with `rake secret` on the bash console substitute *that key* with "MY_SECRET_KEY" from the example.

Once you have done that you should see a `SECRET_KEY_BASE` variable in the `hash` which is returned when you call `ENV` in your rails console.

*Last but not least, reboot your rails app and the error should disappear.*

**Rails app secret key per rbenv-vars**

Further, if you are using `rbenv`, you can use the `rbenv-vars` plugin to achive a per rails app secret key environment variable.

A good read on this would be [here!](https://intercityup.com/blog/deploying-app-env-variables-with-rbenv-passenger-and-capistrano/)

**Using god (godrb.com):** thanks hlcs

You need to `god terminate` and then start again.

Comment: For those who using [god](http://godrb.com/) you need terminate god (`god terminate`) and than start again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar situation with this (perhaps only useful in Ubuntu-like environment).  See: [Missing secret key base for production environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429715/missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment/25438346#25438346). Hope it helps.