# Where is ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] being set in production rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Having trouble with my secrets.yml file in production.

Where is the `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` variable being set in production?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501329/semifixed-missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set it when you start your server:

```
RAILS_ENV=production SECRET_KEY_BASE=****** bundle exec rails server
```

Comment: everytime I restart i have to do this? Is ther a way to save it on the server and load?

Comment: Of course you can write it into a file, maybe an sh script to do this.