# Where is SECRET_KEY_BASE environment variable located when I start Rails app in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the [Rails 4 In Action Book](https://www.manning.com/books/rails-4-in-action), it states that after doing some other setup: the final setup to boot up your rails app in production mode (with web brick) is to enter this command in terminal:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE='rake secret' rails s -e production
```

I am trying to see where the environment variable of `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is stored.

Within `/app/config/secrets.yml` it says that the `secret_key_base` variable is an environment variable:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

But I looked within `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` and the variable `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is not there.

Ultimately I want to know: where is environment variable and its value?  Is it stored somewhere in my rails app?  I hope not for security purposes if I push this app to github.  I assume it is not stored in the app but in my computer system somewhere.  Within a different terminal window I do `echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE` but nothing gets returned.

Thanks in advance for helping me understand the missing pieces.

As a side note: I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792714/where-is-envsecret-key-base-being-set-in-production-rails), but the question is not as detailed and there is no provided answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run this:

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE='rake secret' rails s -e production
```

you are not actually 'saving' the secret key for future you. You're defining it on a one-time basis. Whenever you run a Ruby command you can set temporary environment variables:

```
# from shell
KEY="VAL" OTHER_KEY=OTHER_VAL ruby my_command.rb

# from the ruby script
puts ENV["KEY"] # => "VAL"
puts ENV["OTHER_KEY"] # => "OTHER_VAL"
```

To persist the environment variables you have a couple options. You *could* hard code them in your source code, but this is probably not a good idea because if you push your code to Github, anyone will be able to see it. That's kind of the point of environment variables, anyway, that you can keep them system specific.

**Option A**

You can set them in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

First get the result of `rake secret` (will be a random string) and set a shell variable:

```
KEY=`rake secret` # uses backticks to get command result
```

Then add a line in `bashrc` to export it:

```
echo -e "export SECRET_KEY_BASE=$KEY" >> ~/.bashrc
```

**Option B**

This is the one I'd recommend, you can use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) or [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to manage your environment variables in an app-specific way, i.e. without cluttering up your `bashrc`.

For example with `dotenv` you'd create a `.env` file which contains:

```
# change this to the result of rake secret  
SECRET_KEY_BASE=j3e2dd293d
```

This would be excluded from source control by adding it to gitignore.

Then in your ruby app you call

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
```

and your `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` will be set.

If you want you can make a `.env.example` file (included in source control) which shows which environment variables need to be defined. Then when the app is cloned you can run `mv .env.example .env` and customize `.env`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Follow up question on `SECRET_KEY_BASE='rake secret' rails s -e production`.  I'm still confused about where this is actually set?  It is set within my computer system somewhere but just not accessible?  I don't quite understand how it would be set but then not accessible.  What is the point of setting it at all then? I know why it needs to be set and what it does, but I just don't know how the system accesses it if I can't access it myself.

Comment: When you do it that way (with command line arguments) it's only stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

From you application root, simply type  `bin/rails secret` in the terminal. The generated string can be used as the SECRET_KEY_BASE.
[image: Here is an illustration]