# Missing secret key base for production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My situation is very much like [SemiFixed: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501329/semifixed-missing-secret-key-base-for-production-environment) :

my config/secrets.yml

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

I have added an entry in /etc/environment so that when I log in and type

```
echo $SECRET_KEY_BASE
```

I get the long string I created with rake secret.  But still I get 500 error for Missing secret_key_base for 'production' environment, set this value in config/secrets.yml, even after I reset the entire computer.  So what else can go wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found out that /etc/environment is ignored by apache2.  Add the following to /etc/apache2/envvars solved my problem:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=<the long string>
```

Comment: Im curious if you could link to where you learned this. I am also trying to figure out why I need to place my environment variables there.

Comment: I found /etc/environment was ignored by apache2, so I Googled a little bit and found the solution.  You may also see the accepted answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/146688/why-doesnt-apache2-respect-my-envvars-file but this is Debian/Ubuntu specific, if you use Fedora/CentOS you may have to experiment yourself.

Comment: This happened to me and this solved it. You should mark this as the answer (Even if its your answer :) )